# Mysql select query with CONVERT_TZ not working

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong here?

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `XXXXX` WHERE (`XXXXX` BETWEEN  CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-27 00:00:00','-0:00','-8:00') AND  CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-27 23:59:59','-0:00','-8:00'))

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `XXXXX` WHERE (`XXXXX` BETWEEN '2016-04-27 00:00:00' AND  '2016-04-27 23:59:59')

Both showing equal count. What's wrong in CONVERT_TZ?

Comment: You have too many closed parenthesis.

Comment: I just edited. Count is 0... what is wrong in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have parentheses in the wrong spot. You're calling CONVERT_TZ with only one parameter, in the first case just '2016-04-27 00:00:00'.

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `XXXXXXX` WHERE `XXXXXXXX` BETWEEN  CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-27 00:00:00','UTC','America/Los_Angeles') AND  CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-27 23:59:59','UTC','America/Los_Angeles')
```

Note that in order to use named time zones (like 'UTC' and 'America/Los_Angeles'), the [timezone tables in the mysql system database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html) need to be populated.

Comment: Assuming your code does what you want it to do, there's no error or mistake. There must be no results.

Comment: There are lots of result but in UTC timezone and i want to count in America/Los_Angeles timezone even i try with 04-26 it is still 0. Any suggestion?

Comment: See my edit, there was also extraneous parentheses near your WHERE statement. What datatypes are your columns?

Comment: There are many data types. I tried with above no luck. It is still showing 0 for all 04-26/04-27

Comment: If i try with 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `XXXX` WHERE `XXX` BETWEEN  '2016-04-27 00:00:00' AND  '2016-04-27 23:59:59'

i get 4531

But if i try with above.. i get 0

Comment: Did you set up your time zone tables (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)? What happens if you try converting from -0:00 to -8:00?

Comment: Server timezone is UTC always and i am using same. Do i have to set it up? 0:00 to -8:00 what you mean about it?

Comment: Use '-0:00' and '-8:00' in CONVERT_TZ instead of 'UTC' and 'America/Los Angeles'. You can only use named timezones if you set up mysql's timezone tables.

Comment: It WORK! but same result for both request

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `xxxxxxx` WHERE (`xxxxxxx` BETWEEN  CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-27 00:00:00','-0:00','-8:00') AND  CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-27 23:59:59','-0:00','-8:00'))`

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `xxxxxxx` WHERE (`xxxxxx` BETWEEN '2016-04-27 00:00:00' AND  '2016-04-27 23:59:59')`

COUNT is 4839 for both.... there should be different after conversion right?

Comment: Yes, there should probably be a difference, unless everything happens to be between 2016-04-27 00:00:00 and 2016-04-27 15:59:59, and there's no records between 2016-04-26 15:59:59 and 2016-04-27 00:00:00.

Comment: YES! but it is showing equal records. No idea what's wrong!

Comment: I can't figure it out what's wrong. Can you suggest any?